# What do we mean when we say two elliptic curves are $\mathbb{F}_q$ isomorph?

Tags: elliptic-curves, abelian-varieties

One text i'm reading has the following definition
[image: p]

So i guess $I(t)$ is the set of elliptic curves with $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q) = q + 1-t$, and $N(t)$ is the number of non-equivalent curves. But how is a $\mathbb{F}_q$-isomorphism defined?

EDIT: also, what he means by an isogeny class?

Comment: See [here](https://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/ec.isomorphism) for $K$-isomorphism of elliptic curves.

Comment: An isogeny between two elliptic curves $E,E'$ (defined over some general field) is a non-constant map from $E$ to $E'$, mapping the origin $O$ of $E$ to the origin $O'$ of $E'$. If such an isogeny exists, we call the two curves isogenous. Two elliptic curves can or can not be isogenous, if they are, they can be or not  isomorphic. For finite fields we have a simpler characterization of the isogeny equivalence, taken above as definition. See for instance the survey of Sury, http://www.math.iitb.ac.in/~jkv/acag/sury2.pdf. (Some of the first net search entries.) An isogeny of degree one is an iso